# Delegate not being set (set correctly)

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I'm having trouble figuring out why I'm getting a nil delegate for this call. It seems like I'm setting the delegate just fine.

LogoutViewController.h

```
@protocol SomeNewDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void)someMethod;
@end

@interface LogoutViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SomeNewDelegate> delegate;
```

LogoutViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)logoutButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"logout tapped");
    [self.delegate someMethod];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

MainViewController.m

```
@interface MainViewController () <UIScrollViewDelegate, SomeNewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) LogoutViewController *logoutVC;

@end

@implementation MainViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.logoutVC.delegate = self;
}

- (void)someMethod {
    NSLog(@"someMethod");
}
```

someMethod never gets called and I don't see why the delegate is nil. Any help?

Comment: you have not instantiate the LogoutViewController object

Comment: you have just declare and used that "logoutVC" . . you also have to instantiate this object.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in viewDidload

```
LogoutViewController *logoutVC = [[LogoutViewController alloc]init];
logoutVC.delegate = self;
```

Remove LogoutViewController from property.
I have used this and its working fine.

Hope its working for you.

Edited code in .h file

```
@protocol syncDataDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) offlineSyncProcess;
@end

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController
{
    id <syncDataDelegate> syncDelegate;
}
@property (retain) id syncDelegate;
```

in .m file

```
@implementation LoginViewController
{
  // your code 
}
@synthesize syncDelegate;

- (IBAction)logoutButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"logout tapped");
    [syncDelegate offlineSyncProcess];
}
```

You can call delegate method from here in LoginViewController.m file from any method.

in My Delegate implementation 
in .m file

```
@interface MainViewController ()<syncDataDelegate>

@end
@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     LoginViewController *LVC = [[LoginViewController alloc]init];
     LVC.syncDelegate = self;
}
```

now use the delegate methode here

```
- (void) offlineSyncProcess
{
    // your code here
}
```

this code is working in my project, check this in your project.

Comment: Still not working. Is it something to do with the fact that LogoutViewController is a modal?

Comment: Remove this line [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; and check again that your method is called or not?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your logoutVC is not nil when you try to set the delegate property for it.

You can implement the setDelegate method in your LogoutViewController.m. Then use break point to make sure it is invoked.

Answer (score -1):

Delegate is nil because your logoutVC is nil, you haven't allocated memory to the logoutvc property.

Just before  self.logoutVC.delegate = self 
 Add following code

self.logoutVC = [[LogoutViewController alloc]init];

Everything will start working automatically.

Comment: Can you please add comment what's wrong with this solution, why it has been down voted.